# Why can I not login to my raspberry pi 4b?

Tags: pi-4, ssh, connection, login

I am attempting to log in to my raspberry pi 4b for the first time. I have the wifi file all sorted out and I have a blank file called ssh. I have done `ping raspberrypi.local` and its shows up and responds. When I try to connect to it using `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` it asks for the password. I entered `raspberry` as it is the default password but it denies it. Does anyone know why this might be happening and what the password might be? It is my first time logging in

Comment: Is this a new install? How did you install? Have you read https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/?

Comment: I just got the pi 3/4 ish days ago and installed the official OS with Raspberry Pi Imager. I have not read that and I will do that now

Comment: @Milliways should I rewrite my microSD card?

Comment: Frankly headless install is a black art. Try running with screen and keyboard and it will solve the problem.

Comment: I can't run with screen and keyboard. i need to connect to the pi which I can't

Comment: @Milliways I am thinking of just rewriting my microSD and setting a password as I have no info on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless Pi Zero W 2, SSH over USB fails with permission denied error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136992/headless-pi-zero-w-2-ssh-over-usb-fails-with-permission-denied-error)

Comment: The latest version of the imager can set the default userid, default locale/WiFi country, enable WiFi and enable ssh. Click the gear wheel icon on the front panel to set those things before writing the image to the SDCard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. When using the Raspberry Pi imager, apparently you MUST specify the password you want to use otherwise you can't connect via ssh.
Probably something to do with this:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/raspberry-pi-removes-default-user-to-hinder-brute-force-attacks/

Comment: Ok should I just rewrite my SD card?

Comment: Yes, you have to rewrite the SD card with ssh enabled and username and password specified

Comment: Thank you - it was astonishingly hard to find an answer to this, Google most responded with a ton of pages listing the _old_ default credentials!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know WHY RPT does these things, without any notice and no documentation, and I haven't used the new imager/download, but just follow the "instructions" (some of which are probably impossible if you don't already have a Pi or Linux machine).
This is the way most Linux install works - i.e. assumes you have a screen/keyboard

I always use a screen/keyboard for fresh installs.

You could try Simon Long's Comment:-

"Here is the contents of an example /boot/userconf file:
test:$6$FdsTan/zaR7eKb8B$mSgk/5q/IFMYOVf2e/NdnUfWBi9clSciE1XD2bHsFNDko0k05zouZkbOPjUeDAYTdkLeWWEwjw5Bow0/le/uv1
This sets up a user called ‘test’ with the password ‘pass’ – although bear in mind that if you create an encrypted version of ‘pass’, it is unlikely to be identical to this one, due to the use of what is called a salt to add additional randomness."

Bear in mind that if you do this you would need to change user later with `sudo rename-user`.

It is probably better to **download the latest imager** and follow the
[instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/).

`echo 'raspberrypi' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin`

produces the following:-

`$6$iCCduqhqD1KIBNdu$Z/lTi/pqgbGT2/Rae1EQzNkOyu2Jvaw2wapVGBjV6LPGynxRe4j2jBv5JBeu3YKCiOHlU/e1dbUeQzvx.6bFZ.`

The following userconf.txt file should produce pi/raspberrypi
`pi:$6$iCCduqhqD1KIBNdu$Z/lTi/pqgbGT2/Rae1EQzNkOyu2Jvaw2wapVGBjV6LPGynxRe4j2jBv5JBeu3YKCiOHlU/e1dbUeQzvx.6bFZ.`

although I haven't tested.

Comment: Could I just rewrite my SD card and specify a password?

Comment: I [second that emotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI_0tQdEA5k)! I submitted a comment to [the "blog post"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/), but it was apparently censored, so I'll share it here: "This is a bad idea". But it's a done deal - which won't be *un-done*, so no point in crying over spilt milk. One thing that ***would*** be useful is a script that modifies the modified images to restore the defaults we've had lo these many years. I nominate @Milliways for this job... seconded & unanimously approved. Please keep us posted on progress :)

Answer (score 2):

I created a guide with images to do this [here](https://shiningmantra.com/the-new-headless-raspberry-pi-setup-2022-rpi-org-disowned-username-pi/):

As per the official raspberry blog at https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022 the default username password will no longer be allowed for headless login. This leads the end user in a conundrum as already raspberry pi4’s new HDMI connector cable is not readily available.

Basically there are two methods

1. Use the updated raspberry pi imager too from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager_1.7.2.exe)
2. manually add `userconf` file in the boot directory with `username:encrypted-password` as a single line. to generate encrypted-password string use `echo 'mypassword' | openssl passwd -6 -stdin` tested on win 10

Answer (score 1):

Default username and password is not valid any longer for raspberry Pi.
If you are trying to login headlessly (without monitor/keyboard) you can do it from **Pi Imager** itself.
On Selecting OS in Pi Imager you get an icon of **settings** in which you can

- create a user
- setup wifi
- enable ssh

After configuring , you can continue flashing your Memory Card.
And on first boot you will be good to go

Comment: Jul2023: Used imager: It added a user/password just fine, but I also enabled SSH and that was NOT enabled when I booted. If anyone else has this issue, just add the 'ssh' file to main SD card as we use to do on headless. SSH then worked and was able to use the user/password I created under imager.

Comment: Yes, this is a good trick by adding an `ssh` file to the root of the SD card. And the imager also allow you to tick if you want to enable ssh by default on the first boot.