# Can't SSH on Fresh Install of Raspberry Pi OS lite

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi-os, headless, login, password

this is my first question ever so sorry if I don't follow proper procedure with how I phrase everything. Anyway, I'm trying to set up my raspberry pi for the first time, but am unable to connect to it via ssh using the default username (pi) and password (raspberry) due to a "permission denied" error. I'm running a **headless** setup on Raspberry Pi OS Lite that I downloaded using the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)

What I've done:

1. Install OS unto SD card
2. Create ssh file in boot partition
3. Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file to set up wifi
4. Added `cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory` to `cmdline.txt`. I'm gonna be running a k8s cluster on my pis and according to the guide I'm following, I Need to add this. Mentioning it in case it's relavent to the ssh issues.
5. Added `arm_64bit=1` to `config.txt` (also for the cluster).
6. Then I put the SD card in the pi and booted it up.

After doing all of this, I'm able to ping the pi and get a response. I know I'm using the correct ip address to since I used a seperate tool (Wireless Network Watcher) to get the ip of the pi. Also tried a a new install of the OS, tried ethernet, tried connecting through a different network, and none of those allowed me to connect.

In case it is helpful, here is the full debug output after running `ssh pi@ip-address -vvv`

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.86.51 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.86.51 [192.168.86.51] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+b1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+b1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.86.51:22 as 'pi'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.86.51
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:vzXzzOCUiYDwH9CCGckFSGrUunGOBzZVukpH4sBS+UM
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.86.51
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/erik/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '192.168.86.51' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\erik/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
pi@192.168.86.51's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
pi@192.168.86.51's password:
```

Again, this setup is completely headless, so I have no way of logging in to the pi apart from SSH'ing.

Some extra info for troubleshooting:

1. I've been able to set everything up no issues in my old home. Maybe it's router/network related issues (though I doubt it since I'm able to get the login prompt so SSH probably isn't blocked)
2. Connecting through a Google Mesh Router. Might not be relavent but what do I know

Comment: WHY did you do steps 4, 5? - try a STANDARD setup. Virtually all of your post is Windows error messages - NOTHING to do with Pi.

Comment: Did you read (and follow) https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/? The Pi has NO default default username .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not login to my raspberry pi 4b?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137047/why-can-i-not-login-to-my-raspberry-pi-4b)